# How do i understand actionpack and debug it with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When i reading the source code,I was just not concept or not way to debuging.  To be exact ,I wouldn't know where to begin.

My understanding is:

First I need to read is the routing. But i don't know where is initialization Routes when starting the service. I tried to start with Rake understanding. But I don't know how to correlate them. **It is important, I don't know how they interact**.  I only know superficial concept,  ... What should I do next?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you gone through the official routing guide? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: I agree. Don't read the source code. Read the docs. They are mostly excellent.

Comment: @normalocity yes i did.

Comment: @matt Thanks, my english not so well... :-P

Comment: Also I recommend the O'Reilly "Learning Rails" book. It isn't perfect but it does explain basics like routing very well.

Comment: @matt Well, I know a lot of methods,and how to use. But I want the more in-depth study, but do not know how to start.

Answer (score 0):

The routes are usually defined in `config/routes.rb` and you can test that they're working correctly by running `rake routes` to see how they're interpreted.

If you keep your routing table simple, which is best done by following a strict REST-ful approach, then you'll have entries like:

```
resources :users
```

If you diverge from the REST-ful approach, which is sometimes necessary, be aware that it will complicate your routing file, so be cautious before doing this.

`rake` is a general utility used by Rails and other Ruby applications to perform utility functions. In the Rails world it's primarily used for executing `rake test` and `rake routes` as most of the other functions are handled by the `rails` command itself.

Comment: I'm sorry,i just want understand how to initialize when running  instance(project). Thanks for you help

Comment: How to initialize what? The application?

Comment: Yes, for example like the startup and require sequence for server.

Comment: `rails server` should be how you get the application booted, but using [Pow](http://pow.cx/) is a better option if you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with reading some Rails Guides (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/)

Debugging Rails Applications would be a good start
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html